# How can I convert an emoji string to it's icon while writing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently developing my own chat. Now I want to extend my chat input so that when I enter for example `:-)`, it should instantly change to  when I write inside my contenteditable div (which makes it more complex).

I've tried to find out how WhatsApp Web does this but I'm not really coming forward. This is my code:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
 $( "#input" ).keypress( function ( e ) {
  if ( e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey ) {
   $( "#messages" ).scrollTop( $( "#messages" ).prop( "scrollHeight" ) );
   $( "#messages" ).append( "<div class=\"message right\">" + $( this ).html() + "</div>" );
   $( this ).html( "" );
      e.preventDefault();
  }
 } );
  
  $( "#input" ).on( "input", function () {
   console.log( $( this ).html() );
  } );
} );
```

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#messages > div { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.divider span {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.date-area {
  margin-top: -35px;
}

.spacer {
  height: 35px;
}

#input {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    display: block;
    color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
</div>
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter a message"></div>
```

The interesting thing with WhatsApp Web is that when I press the deletion key, the emoji goes back to `:-)`. How do they do it? Is there an extension? I'd be cool if I didn't need an extension.

**Update**

I've updated my code and added an input function.

Comment: @freedomn-m Sure! It's my chat and my input to write a new message I'm talking about... Currently he is not yet doing what I asked in this question, so I asked the question (which would otherwise be unnecessary).

Comment: Ok, so your provided code has nothing to do with the question, so the standard SO response when no code is provided is: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @freedomn-m I think it has because it's about my chat and my contenteditable div (my chat input where I write my emojis e.g. :-) ). At the moment I know how to replace something in a string which will helps me as soon as I know how to listen on my div input and do a live replace with an icon. If I have this, I can handle everything else by my own and post an answer. Thats my actual plan :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried this, but here's a general idea:

Maintain a dictionary(ie, a JS object) that maps all the text emojis to an actual emoji's hex-code. The hex-code corresponding to most common emojis are available here :
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_smileys.asp

```
 const emojiMap = {
                        ":-)" : "&#1F60A", //happy face
                        ":-(" :  "&#1F641", //sad face
                        /**...and so on...**/
                     }
```

Now you can check if your input string matches anything from this map and then render the corresponding HTML hex-code to the DOM, like :

```
//Just some pseudo code, please change implementation as per your need.

if(inputString.includes(':-)')){
                render(emojiMap[':-)']);
         }
```

Comment: And what should I do with this? I'm confused.

Comment: @Mr.Jo  I've edited my original response, please check

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach.

Create an array with objects of the following class.

```
class Emoji {
    constructor(emojiSymbol, textCode) {

        this.symbol = symbol; // :-)
        this.textCode = textCode; // &#1F60A
    }
}
```

I assume that users text will be saved as a string when its typed.

**Regarding --->** *Now I want to extend my chat input so that when I enter for example :-), it should instantly change to*

You have to keep track of the user input. 
To be more specific you have to create a function that will check every **word** that the user writes.
If its found inside the array of Emoji **symbols**, it will remove the **symbol** and it will replace it with the **textcode**.

-- The function will be enabled if a word has 3 or more characters.

-- The function will stop working after the user press space or if there are more than 5 or 6 consecutive characters, depends how large is the symbols for the emoji.

**Example String ->** I am going to work :-)

1) It will check the **I**.

Because the word is less that three characters the function wont be enabled

2) It will check the **am**.
Same as 1.

3) It will check the **going**.

When the user types the third character "**i**" the function will be enabled.
It will save the index of the 'g' character.
The index can be calculated: Total length of the current text message - 3.

It will take the **goi** and start looking inside the array of Emoji objects **symbol** if it finds a corresponding one it will replace it with the textCode inside the Emoji class.

User types the fourth character it will start looking for the "goin"......

4) It will check the **to**.

Same as 1 and 2.

5) It will check the **work**

Same as 3.

6) It will check the **:-)**

Same as 3 with the difference that it will find the object inside the array with the corresponding **symbol** and it will replace it with the **textCode**.

**Regarding -->** *The interesting thing with WhatsApp Web is that when I press the deletion key, the emoji goes back to :-). How do they do it? Is there an extension? I'd be cool if I didn't need an extension.*

When the user press delete button, You have to check backwards up to a specific number of consecutive characters. if they correspond to an emoji you replace the textCode with a symbol.

**Example String ->** I am going to work &#1F60A

I assume that the :-) corresponds to this textCode -> &#1F60A.

The function will search backwards. 
It will save the ending index which will be the index of "**A**" (&#1F60A) and the starting index will be "&".
If it finds an object with the same **textCode** it will replace it with the **symbol**.